# Python dart scoreboard not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have already asked a question about this project, since asking that one i have fixed the error in that question. However, i now run into another problem. This time i have made it so that the python program checks if the number that has been entered is more than 180(the maximum allowed score in darts), but now when i enter something more than 180 it seemingly takes the number away still. Any help would be appreciated.
The code:
http://pastebin.com/XvWRJjWA

Comment: If you have asked a question already then you should know that the code should be included in the question and not linked.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm going to edit the code into the question for him ;)

Comment: Stupid edit queue

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if (minusnum2 > 180):
   cumulative2 += minusnum2
```

But I think you want:

```
if (minusnum2 <= 180):
    cumulative2 += minusnum2
```

Also, instead of having all of these duplicated methods, I would refactor this using a class. You can then have instance variables for the names (stored as a tuple of player0, player1) and the score (a list of score0, score1) instead of relying on globals.

Then, have a single method that takes a player number (0 or 1) as a parameter and runs through the score logic for that player (self.name[player] and self.score[player]). Once you do that, you can use this line of code to toggle between player 0 and player 1 inside a loop until a winner is found:

```
player = 1 - player
```

The logic being that if player is 0, 1 - 0 sets it to 1 and if player is 1, 1 - 1 sets it to 0.